# EventHandler ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, delegates, eventhandler

I have a project in ASP.NET CORE. I want to call a method (in the future several methods) before my RejectExchange method from ExchangeService class is finished. So I read about EventHandlers to do it, but I don't know where excatly I should assign methods to a delegate. I have ExchangeService class:

```
public class ExchangeService : IExchange
{
    private readonly SocialNetworkContext _context;
    private readonly IUser _userService;
    private readonly IItem _itemService;
    private readonly IExchangeRequestNotification _exchangeRequestNotificationService;

    public event EventHandler<Exchange> ExchangeRejecting;

    protected virtual void OnExchangeRejecting(Exchange exchange)
    {
        ExchangeRejecting?.Invoke(this, exchange);
    }

    public void RejectExchange(int id)
    {
        var exchange = GetById(id);

        OnExchangeRejecting(exchange);

        Delete(exchange);
    }

    public ExchangeService(SocialNetworkContext context, IUser userService, IItem itemService, IExchangeRequestNotification exchangeRequestNotificationService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userService = userService;
        _itemService = itemService;
        _exchangeRequestNotificationService = exchangeRequestNotificationService;            
    }
}
```

And I want to delete notification about exchange, before exchange will be deleted, in ExchangeRequestNorificationService, so I created method OnExchangeRejecting:

```
public class ExchangeRequestNotificationService : IExchangeRequestNotification
{
    private readonly SocialNetworkContext _context;
    private readonly IUser _userService;

    public ExchangeRequestNotificationService(SocialNetworkContext context, IUser userService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public void OnExchangeRejecting(object source, Exchange exchange) => Delete(GetByExchangeId(exchange.Id));    

    public void Delete(ExchangeRequestNotification exchangeRequestNotification)
    {
        _context.Remove(exchangeRequestNotification);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Everything is fine but I don't understand where I have to assign methods to a delegate. I have ExchangeController where I use dependency injection and pass IExchangeService to constructor and there I assign methods to delegate:

```
public ExchangeController(IExchange exchangeService, IExchangeRequestNotification exchangeRequestNotification, IChat chatService)
    {
        _exchangeService = exchangeService;
        _exchangeRequestNotificationService = exchangeRequestNotification;
        exchangeService.ExchangeRejecting += _exchangeRequestNotificationService.OnExchangeRejecting;
        exchangeService.ExchangeRejecting += chatService.OnExchangeRejecting;
    }
```

But I think it's not right, because in this controller I don't really need ExchangeRequestNotificationService and ChatService (which also has method OnExchangeRejecting), I only need ExchangeService. ExchangeRequestNotificationService is passed to controller only for assign methods to a delegate on method OnRejectingExchange and in the futhure it will be worse (more not needed services injected).

My question is where I should excatly assign methods to a delegate? Sorry for my english, I hope that you understand my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been asking myself the same question and I came across your post on stackoverflow. Since I did not find a solution on the net, I tried to solve it myself.

For the solution I used the library Autofac as DI provider and configured my services, which exposed an EventHandler via the Lifetime events of Autofac.

Example:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyService>().InstancePerRequest().OnActivated(e =>
{
    var dep = e.Context.Resolve<MyEventHandler>();
    e.Instance.EntitySaved += dep.OnEntitySaved;
});
```

So I can guarantee that the EventHandler is always registered, wherever my service is injected. I've chosen the OnActivated lifetime event instead of OnActivating to avoid circular-dependency problems; e.g. if MyService should be used indirectly by the EventHandler.

Best regards,
Daniel